# How can I loop through 2 elements at the same time in jinja?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have two elements and need to cylcle through both of them at the same time, but in JINJA(!). Naturally I tried to use zip() to go through both (list and dict) at the same time, but jinja does not allow that

```
 {% for (i, o) in zip(searches, e_links): %}
      <a href="/sid/{{ o }}">
      <div>{{ i.time_string }}</div>
```

Error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'zip' is undefined
```

Is there another way for cycling through two items at the same time in jinja, or is it somehow possible to pass the zip() function to jinja?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve this if anybody in the future wants to know. You can simply zip() the two items before passing them to jinja like such:

```
return render_template('results.html', packed=zip(searches, e_links))
```

in the template then simply cycle through the zipped item:

```
{% for i, o in packed: %}
```

And yes, all in all it took me more than an hour to figure this one out.

Comment: Interesting for Django/Flask users, but does not really answers the question, as it does not solve the problem by using Jinja.

Comment: It does answer the question. You simply need to zip() the items before passing them to Jinja. In Jinja you can then simply loop through the zipped items at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you must adhere to use only `jinja`, you can utilize something like this:

```
authors = [
{%- set names = cookiecutter.author_name.split(',') -%}
{%- set emails = cookiecutter.author_email.split(',') -%}
{%- for i in range(0, names|length) %}
    { name = "{{ names[i].strip() }}", email = "{{ emails[i].strip() }}" },
{%- endfor %}
]
```

In software such as `cookiecutter`, it is easy to run Python code to pass parameters into Jinja. The example shows how to use the "cookiecutter" variable, but it should be easily replacable by `searches` and `e_links`.